# how can I transform netcdf data from a rotated pole to normal grid?

Tags: datagrid, netcdf, cdo-climate

Hy everyone,

I'm struggling with the transformation of netcdf data that comes from a climate model simulation and is on a rotated grid.

This is how my file is built up.
I want to make some plots and stuff with the TOT_PREC variable.

It says, taht the grid mapping is rotated pole, but the coordinates are lat and lon? How can i understand this?

Does anybody know how to tranform the data so I can adress it with real worl lat and lon?

'TOT_PREC': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 TOT_PREC(time, rlat, rlon)
standard_name: precipitation_amount
long_name: total precipitation amount
units: kg m-2
grid_mapping: rotated_pole
coordinates: lat lon
cell_methods: time: sum
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (14, 438, 450)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,

'rotated_pole': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
|S1 rotated_pole()
long_name: coordinates of the rotated North Pole
grid_mapping_name: rotated_latitude_longitude
grid_north_pole_latitude: 39.25
grid_north_pole_longitude: -162.0
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = ()
filling on, default _FillValue of  used,
'height_2m': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>

'lon': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lon(rlat, rlon)
standard_name: longitude
long_name: longitude
units: degrees_east
_CoordinateAxisType: Lon
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (438, 450)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,

'lat': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lat(rlat, rlon)
standard_name: latitude
long_name: latitude
units: degrees_north
_CoordinateAxisType: Lat
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (438, 450)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,

'rlon': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 rlon(rlon)
standard_name: projection_x_coordinate
long_name: rotated longitude
units: degrees
axis: X
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (450,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,

'rlat': <class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 rlat(rlat)
standard_name: projection_y_coordinate
long_name: rotated latitude
units: degrees
axis: Y
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (438,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used,

I already tried cdo commands but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: This shoud be easy to do given it's from a climate model, which should have CF-compliant netCDF data. Can you provide the data as part of the question? Or at least tell us the model

Comment: I've made the simulation myself on a server, it's the COSMO CLM Model. 
data is here: [link](/we.tl/t-8pvMcwdOxl )
thanks so far

Comment: Please add this to the question, and also tell us what you tried in CDO and why if failed. If CDO failed it’s most likely you need to modify the file. It’s fairly robust